# Add "placeholder" in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

In my iOS app I have a simple view to which I have added a TabBar and a Navigation Bar programmatically. I have added several GUI elements with Interface Builder. Now I have the problem that my view on the phone looks different to the one in Interface Builder due to the missing bars. How do I make the xib in Interface Builder look the same as the actual view?

Comment: If you added those view programatically there is no way to do it. Add those elements in Interfece Builder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NavigationBar and Tabbar can be added in the interface builder to make it look like the one running on phone.

To do so, open the RightUtilities, Select the attributesInspector, and check out simulated metrics. 
You can set the top bar, as well as bottom tab bar.

[image: Xcode Screenshot]